# gDEBugger gives me error on glLinkProgram but executing normally works (QGLWidget in Qt5)

Tags: opengl, glsl, qt5, qglwidget

I want to debug my application but when i run it, i receive errors on the **glLinkProgram** and i cannot see an output visually in the debugger execution.

While debugging, in the "shader" code view i see a red line saying that the program cannot be linked because i **have to write to gl_Position**.

But my shaders are like this:

```
#version 440

in vec3 VertexPosition;
in vec3 VertexColor;
in vec2 UV;
in float MaxVal;

out vec3 outColor;
out vec2 outUV;
out float outMaxVal;

void main()
{
    outColor = VertexColor;
    outUV = UV;
    outMaxVal = MaxVal;
    gl_Position = vec4( VertexPosition, 1.0 );
}
```

And fragment:

```
#version 440

in vec3 outColor;
in vec2 outUV;
in float outMaxVal;

uniform sampler2D filterTex;

out vec4 FragColor;

void main() {

    float texColor = texture( filterTex, outUV ).r;
    texColor = texColor * outMaxVal;
    FragColor = vec4(outColor.rgb * texColor,1.0f);

}
```

When i execute my code i can see the result of the compilation and the shaders, apparently work perfectly, but i want to debug and this has no sense.

Besides, using QGLWidget in the gDEBugger i see **three contexts created**, the first two deleted. The active one is the third. I Do nothing about them, i just use the widget. Who builds those contexts? Could it give me errors?

*** UPDATE *** here i add what i did to check errors. I get all strings empty... shouldn't they have contained any kind of information?

```
GLint status;
glFuncs.glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
if (status == GL_FALSE) {
    int loglen;
    char logbuffer[1000];
    glFuncs.glGetProgramInfoLog(programHandle, sizeof(logbuffer), &loglen, logbuffer);
    fprintf(stderr, "OpenGL Program Linker Error \n%.*s", loglen, logbuffer);
} else {
    int loglen;
    char logbuffer[1000];
    glFuncs.glGetProgramInfoLog(programHandle, sizeof(logbuffer), &loglen, logbuffer);
    if (loglen > 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "OpenGL Program Link OK \n%.*s", loglen, logbuffer);
    }
    glFuncs.glValidateProgram(programHandle);
    glFuncs.glGetProgramInfoLog(programHandle, sizeof(logbuffer), &loglen, logbuffer);
    if (loglen > 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "OpenGL Program Validation results:\n%.*s", loglen, logbuffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this on Windows? If so, at least one of those contexts is created simply to load the new set of extensions necessary to create a context. Sounds silly, but that is the way WGL works. GLX has new context creation extensions too, but they can be loaded before a context is created ;)

Comment: Yes! The calls after those creatinons have that "w" on the calls (Probably fron WGL). 
it is on Windows 7. Do you know why i get no output, and link is failing?

Comment: No idea why linking would fail, to be honest. This all looks valid for GL 4.4. Have you checked the compiler/linker info logs?

Comment: As i said, " i have to write to gl_Position." is what i receive from gDEBugger. Nothing else. About the link error, i could not find a way to get the text of the error in Visual Studio, honestly.

Comment: Stop using gDEBugger, and call the actual `glGetProgramInfoLog (...)` and `glGetShaderInfoLog (...)` functions.

Comment: I added info about what i did to check errors. All strings were size 0. Why?

Comment: Was this ever resolved?  I'm having the exact same issue :(

Comment: I stopped using gDEBugger and finished my project anyway :-(